# What condition did River have in To the Moon?

Tags: to-the-moon

Throughout To the Moon, Eva and Neil mention that River had a certain condition that causes someone to answer questions literally (that's how I took it but it probably had another effect).

What condition are they referring to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

River has [Asperger's syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome), which is an autism spectrum disorder than can cause difficulties in social interaction.

This is evidenced by the doctor's recommendation that Johnny read some of the books written by [Tony Attwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Attwood), a psychologist who has written several books on Asperger's syndrome.

Answer (score 4):

River's condition is known as Asperger's syndrome, a form of autism that make social interaction hard and unwanted. The signs that she shows are:

- She shies away from new people.
- She's assigned several books on the condition to read.
- The sound of a ticking clock makes her nervous